# How to save as string each item selected in listbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

I have a listbox with 5 items (see screenshot). For each item selected, I want it to be saved as string so I can use them down below my code. I have a loop but it puts the selected items separated by a comma. I want individual strings though. How can this loop be modified to save each varItem as string as it loops?

```
Dim strParameters, varItem, strComma as string
strComma = ","
For Each varItem In Me!LstParameters.ItemsSelected
        strParameters = strParameters & Me!LstParameters.ItemData(varItem)
        strParameters = strParameters & strComma
        Next varItem
        strParameters = CStr(Left$(strParameters, Len(strParameters) - 1))
```

Here is my listbox. I want the 2 selected items to be individually in a string.

[image]

Comment: `Me!LstParameters.ItemData(varItem)` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @taller, Where can I fit your suggestion in the above loop?

Comment: It depends what's your next step. eg. `For Each varItem In Me!LstParameters.ItemsSelected :  MsgBox Me!LstParameters.ItemData(varItem) : Next varItem`

Comment: It does loop and displays each selected item in the msgbox. However, how do I save each item in a string?

Comment: What does `save` mean? What's your next step?

Comment: As I loop through each selected item, I want it saved in a string. For example, if I select `RiverFlows` I want to save as something like `strRiverFlows` =  `Me!LstParameters.ItemData(varItem)`. And then do the same for the next item. However, the next item need to have a different string name.

Comment: If you want to store multiple strings, pls use string array. _Microsoft documentation:_

> [Using arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-arrays?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: Because all of my listbox items are different I don't want to save all of them as the same name. RiverDepth must be strRiverDepth, volume must be strvolume. If I save every list item under the same name how can I distinguish my listbox items from one to another?

Comment: Note that in your declaration statement, only strComma would be a String type. The others would be Variant. VBA requires explicit declaration of type for each variable, otherwise will default to Variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Collection or a Dictionary which allow referencing items by a key name - an Array does not. Example with Collection, a Dictionary would be basically same.

```
Sub BuildCollection()
Dim colS As Collection, varItem As Variant
Set colS = New Collection
'Build 5-item collection
colS.Add Null, "strRiverDepth"
colS.Add Null, "strRiverFlow"
colS.Add Null, "strTurbidity"
colS.Add Null, "strVolume"
colS.Add Null, "strSomething"
'populate collection items with listbox selections
For Each varItem In Me.LstParameters.ItemsSelected
    colS("str" & Me.LstParameters.ItemData(varItem)) = Me.LstParameters.ItemData(varItem)
Next varItem
'do something with collection items
Debug.Print colS("strRiverDepth")
Debug.Print colS("strRiverFlow")
Debug.Print colS("strTurbidity")
Debug.Print colS("strVolume")
Debug.Print colS("strSomething")
End Sub
```

Debug output of selection example will be like:
RiverDepth
RiverFlow
Null
Null
Null

It is not necessary to pre-build collection. Could instead use `colS.Add` within listbox loop. Collection will then only have number of items that were selected.
`colS.Add Me.LstParameters.ItemData(varItem), "str" & Me.LstParameters.ItemData(varItem)`

Alternative is to declare 5 variables and then within listbox loop have a `Select Case` structure to determine which variable to populate.

```
strItem = Me.LstParameters.ItemData(varItem)
Select Case strItem
    Case "RiverDepth"
         strRiverDepth = strItem
    Case "RiverFlow"
         strRiverFlow = strItem
    Case "Turbidity"
         strTurbidity = strItem
    Case "Volume"
         strVolume = strItem
    Case "Something"
         strSomething = strItem
End Select
```

And no, cannot dynamically construct variable name. Cannot do: `"str" & strItem = strItem`

If you want collection or variables available to other procedures or modules, declare them as Public/Global in module header. Then in whatever procedure uses these entities to accomplish something, will probably want to clear them.

Also, TempVars are another option. Again, would need to instantiate and set 5, similarly as done for variables.

Comment: The `Select Case` worked really well @June7.  Thank you so much for your solution.